# Using a var with $.getScript()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `$.getScript()` to call an external file. Is it possible to pass a variable value when it's called?

example:

```
var passVal = "ch967";
$.getScript(ext.js); //how can I use `passVal` within ext.js
```

ext.js

```
if(passVal=="ch967"){
   var a = "Relax Chairs"
} else {
   var a = "Table Chairs"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to pass a variable value when it's called?

Not directly, no, you have to put it somewhere global that the script then accesses it from. That could be

- A global variable
- `sessionStorage`

...or just about any other global state that the script could detect.

Comment: Thanks TJ Crowder. I tried as `var window.passVal = "ch967"; $.getScript(ext.js);` But doesn't work? Is this wrong?

Comment: @Becky: That will create a global, yes. `ext.js` will need to use that global.

Comment: @Becky: Either of those would work in `ext.js`. The first will work unless you've shadowed the `window` variable (e.g., done `var window` in a function or similar). The second will work unless you've shadowed the `passVal` variable (e.g., done `var passVal` in a function or similar).

Comment: Thanks. I've made a typo... declaring a global var worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have just to declare your variable in global scope, example :

```
window.passVal = "ch967";
```

Like this you can access to your variable in external script called by `$.getScript`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible, global variable declared in inline javascript is accessible in external javascript page loaded using `$.getScript()`

if

`var passVal = "ch967";` not work

try

```
window.passVal = "ch967";
```

than

```
$.getScript("ext.js");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variables in this way:

```
var passVal = "ch967";
$.getScript('ext.js?passVal='+passVal);
```

And then in ext.js file you need 2 things: a new function and usage of it to get your param:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

getParameterByName('passVal');
```